# python turtle causes errors

Tags: python, function

Just learned python and I saw the turtle module, I tried using it with this Line (That was the instruction):

```
new_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
```

And it caused these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/Practices.py", line 2, in <module>
import turtle
  File "D:\Python\lib\turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
import tkinter as TK
  File "D:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2091
print("Exception in Tkinter callback", file=sys.stderr)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Couldn't find answeres for specifficaly these errors.
I want to ask why it happens here, but also a less specific questions:
How come built in python functions cause errors? I also have errors when debugging with PyCharm, and the fact that built in functions and features cause errors kinda annoy me.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed like you're using a Python 2 interpreter with a Python 3 site packages directory. Given the error points to the print statement in the tkinter library and only Python 2 interpreters will raise a `SyntaxError` when encountering a print function.

You should go to the "Project Interpreter" settings and choose a correct interpreter and Python version (probably the one under `D:\Python\`, which is for Python 3).

To simplify things, you can also create a venv as the project interpreter which helps you create a semi-isolated environment for your interpreter and all its dependencies. You can do so by clicking the "gear" icon next to Project Interpreter and choose "Add" then "Virtualenv Environment".

I also recommend you to not write files in Python's source directory (`D:\Python`) as it can mess the PATH up.

Comment: If you want to use python 2.7 with turtle, just choose a Python 2.7 Interpreter (not the one under `D:\Python` that's for sure), turtle is available for both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the stupid questions, I just began python:
1. Should I keep only the python files in the python folder or is it ok to keep stuff like Pycharm there?
2. What should I choose for base interepter, Python 2.7 D:\Python\python.exe? Because when I choose that and add it pops up a window that tells me to make sure my Python version is supported by the package.
3. What do you mean semi-isolated, just wanna know.

Comment: @Nadavs2310 If you're new to Python, I would suggest you to start learning Python 3 and not 2, since [Python 2 is legacy, Python 3 is the present and future](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3). And for your questions 1. Conventionally we keep nothing in the base Python folder excepted for the stuff that comes with Python when you installed it. You should create a "projects" folder elsewhere and store your scripts/projects there. 2. If your tutorial uses Python 2.7, yes, choose the 2.7 Interpreter and say "yes" to the pop up. If your tutorial uses Python 3, choose a 3.x Interpreter.

Comment: I finished the Codecademy course which uses Python 2.7, I have to learn 2.7 for some reasons.
When I choose 2.7 it pops up with this:
 2018.1.4\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 155, in main
    do_untar(name)
  File "D:\Python\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 96, in do_untar
    import tarfile
  File "D:\Python\lib\tarfile.py", line 47, in <module>
    import shutil
  File "D:\Python\lib\shutil.py", line 12, in <module>
    import collections
  File "D:\Python\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 54
    yield from reversed(self._mapping)
Syntax erro

Comment: 3. When I said "semi-isolated environment", I mean that the virtual environment will create its own copy of site-packages (or lib), and it's own copy of python.exe and its components. Venv will also modify your PATH to the venv's. This would help you avoid the problem you're having right now where there's a Python 2/3 mess up. Using venv is very useful for keeping track and isolating different projects. The "semi" part is because venv always fallback on the base system stuff when it isn't present within the venv (you don't really have to worry about this part).

Comment: Could Uninstalling Python and Pycharm and then reinstalling fix all this mess maybe?

Comment: IMO, the easiest thing to do right now for you is to delete the whole `D:\Python` folder and uninstall python itself, and reinstall a clean version of Python and/or Pycharm (if you have your own scripts in there, copy it elsewhere). Since (I don't know how, but you managed) the Python folder is very messed up, when only the essentials should be in the base folder. Note when you install the fresh versions: don't put everything in the Python folder, and perhaps have a read of http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv/.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, it works after the reinstallation, also sorry for the probably annoying questions.

Comment: @Nadavs2310 No prob, I suspect many other new programmers might have experienced similar problems. This QA might've be able to help answer some of the questions.